# html5 audio Setting volume with javascript not effective

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have this simple tiny .mp3 that has to be played on new message. It plays well but i can't seam to control the volumelevel of it.
I've this Jfidle http://jsfiddle.net/Ls9ef0zo/14/ prepared with a visual audio element. Ofcourse i don't want it to be visible in the real environment.

```
 <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"
  oninput="outputUpdate(value)"/>                                                       


  var newmsgsound = document.createElement('audio');
  newmsgsound.setAttribute('src',
  http://chat.transonly.nl/sounds/sound_1.mp3');
  newmsgsound.setAttribute('id', 'newmsgsound');
  newmsgsound.setAttribute('controls', 'controls');
  body.appendChild(newmsgsound);

  function outputUpdate(vol) {
  var audiolevel = document.getElementById('newmsgsound');
  audiolevel.volume=vol;
  }
```

***edit***
Not sure where to update the question as partialy answered so i'll do it here?

Thanks to the anwers provided the audio-element actually responds now to the slider-event however!..In my own environment (Not Fidle)
The sound played by the audio-element is not affected by it. I can see it is responding. Even when i set it to 'Mute' on the audio-element itself the sound gets played out loud.
Isn't that ought?

**edit2***
I should be very ashamed now!!!
I was hearing the sound of a browser i'd hidden and was sending test messages to that one. :-)
It's ok now!

Comment: Try adding the event listener in the same place as the function definition.

Comment: If you set your jsfiddle to "no wrap in body" it will work : http://jsfiddle.net/Ls9ef0zo/19/

Comment: Indeed that worked. It's a typical setting for Fidle?

Comment: The default value is "onload", which wrap your code into an onload event, making you variables scoped. You were having a trouble with the way you assigned your function call in inline HTML, your outputUpdat function being also scoped, therefore it wasn't defined for your HTML. Personnaly I avoid defining event handlers inline. Also, one solution may have been to declare your function as `window.outputUpdate = function(vol) {...`

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Your code is fine. <strike>You need to define the outputUpdate() function before referring it in volumeslider.</strike>
You simply need to tweak jsfiddle to have "no wrap in body".

```
 <script>
     var newmsgsound = document.createElement('audio');
     newmsgsound.setAttribute('src', 'http://chat.transonly.nl/sounds/sound_1.mp3');
     newmsgsound.setAttribute('id', 'newmsgsound');
     newmsgsound.setAttribute('controls', 'controls');
     document.body.appendChild(newmsgsound);

     function outputUpdate(vol) {      
        var audiolevel = document.getElementById('newmsgsound');
        audiolevel.volume=vol;
    }   
    </script>

    <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" oninput="outputUpdate(value)"/>
```

Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KySKyqmGDU0lKdQVjFf9?p=preview)

Comment: Just saw your comment above. Apparently jsfiddle showed `Uncaught ReferenceError: outputUpdate is not defined` on console but it worked fine when I copy-pasted the code on plunkr. Thanks for pointing out. Updating answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797262/html5-audio-setting-volume-with-javascript-not-effective#comment-49644012

Comment: Well, the script actually resides in a .js that is in the head off the page where the html is. Strange thing now is that (even with the audio element visible and responding to the slider) the mp3 is played at the same level. Even when i set it to Mute on the audioelement the sound plays on new message.....

Answer (score 0):

You function output update is not used now.

try something like this.

```
 var newmsgsound = document.createElement('audio');
 newmsgsound.setAttribute('src', 'http://chat.transonly.nl/sounds/sound_1.mp3');
 newmsgsound.setAttribute('id', 'newmsgsound');
 newmsgsound.setAttribute('controls', 'controls');
 document.body.appendChild(newmsgsound);
 var audiolevel = document.getElementById('newmsgsound');
 var value = document.getElementById('volumeslider').value;
 audiolevel.volume=value;
```

Comment: Yes it is (inline html) + 
and how do you update it to something else than the input's default value ?